# xslt matching a dynamic template

Tags: xslt, matching

I am having an xslt issue that I cannot seem to solve. Right now I have this template match: `<xsl:template match="bodytext/p[position() = 4]">`

And this works fine. When the 4th paragraph renders I include some content. The issue is that sometimes the `<p>` element can have a class `class="exclude"`

I am trying to find a good way to exclude the `<p>` tags that have that class attribute. The problem is that there can be as many `<p class="exclude">` as wanted/needed before or at the 4th paragraph while still rendering the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd paragraphs that do not have "exclude" class. So if a document looks like:

```
<p></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

I only want to match the template:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Another example would be an input of:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p class="exclude"></p>
<p></p>
```

and output of:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
    select="bodytext/p[not(@class = 'exclude')][position() = 4]"/>
```

Here's the test case. Applying the following transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="bodytext/p[not(@class = 'exclude')][position() = 4]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To:

```
<bodytext>
    <p></p>
    <p class="exclude"></p>
    <p class="exclude"></p>
    <p class="exclude"></p>
    <p></p>
    <p class="exclude"></p>
    <p></p>
    <p>test</p>
</bodytext>
```

Produces:

```
<p>test</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I would also like to render the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd paragraph along with the 4th, 5th .. etc. Just exclude the "exclude" ones

Comment: @kevinsufferdini, then just drop the `[position() = 4]` predicate. in your question you asked for the 4th paragraph so that's why it's there in my answer.

Comment: first of all, thanks. This has helped. But I want to say that while the page is excluding the "exclude" p tags from rendering, the webpage still thinks they are there. I am attempting to render some html after the 4th paragraph no matter how many "excludes" are between the 1st and 4th paragraph regardless of how many "excludes" there are before it. With your code, if the first two paragraphs are "excludes" and the second two paragraphs are normal <p> tags, the html I want to render is rendering after the 2nd <p> even when the two "exclude" paragraphs are not rendering. I hope that is clear

Comment: Just to clarify, continuing my previous example: if the first two paragraphs are "exclude" classes, then the html I want to render should be rendering after the 6th <p> assuming that the following four <p> elements do not have exludes

Comment: @kevinsufferdini, I would suggest you update your question with a more specific example. Or ideally accept this one as resolved and post a new one. Your comment goes beyond what you have asked originally and an example that would illustrate what you're trying to accomplish would help. I am sure I will misinterpret your "requirements" if I go solely by what's in your last comment.

Comment: oh and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036059/matching-a-dynamic-xslt-template

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bodytext/p[@class = 'exclude']"/>

<xsl:template match="bodytext/p[not(@class = 'exclude')][4]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- new content goes here -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. Are all these xsl functions compatible with xsl 1.0? That is what I am using

Comment: There is nothing in there that is specific to XSLT 2.0 so the code should do the same with an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor.

Comment: Getting a org.apache.xpath.XPathProcessorException: CONTINUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR